# how to show tipboxes for dynamically added content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page where some content is added via a javascript function call.
Some items on the page have tipboxes assigned. For ones which are present since the page loading tipboxes are displayed. While for the dynamically added content they are not displayed. 
I use   http://code.google.com/p/jquery-tipbox/downloads/list  tipbox tool

Sounds like the issue is unclear without example. So, the code

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tipbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/my_js_functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function(){  

    $("#ele1_id").tipbox("tipbox message 1", 0);
    $("#ele2_id").tipbox("tipbox message 2", 0);
    $("#inc1").tipbox("tipbox message 3", 0);
    $("#inc2").tipbox("tipbox message 4", 0);
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<center>

<div style="visibility:visible"  >
<input id='ele1_id' type='radio' name='test' value='test1'
onClick=get_fields(id,checked)
> test 1 option <br>

<input id='ele2_id' type='radio' name='test' value='test2'
onClick=get_fields(id,checked)
>test 2 option <br>

</div>
</div></td><td alighn=center>
<div style='visibility:hidden' id='parameters'></div>
<div style='visibility:hidden' id='parameters_extra'></div>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

my_js_functions.js :

```
function add_fields(name,value){

     var target=document.getElementById('parameters_extra');
     var content2="";
   if (name == 'ele1_id') {
   if (value == 'sele1') {
    content2="<table><tr><td id='inc1'>\
<b> text to which I want to have tipbox assigned (tipbox message 3) </b></td>\
<td><input type='text' maxlength=5 name='inp_value1' ></td></tr></table>";
   }
   else if (value == 'sele2') {
    content2="<table><tr><td id='inc2'>\
<b> another text for which 'tipbox message 4' has to appear </b></td>\
<td><input type='text' maxlength=5 name='inp_value2' ></td></tr></table>";
   }
  }
     target.innerHTML = content2;
     target.style.visibility = "visible";


return false;

}

function get_fields(el,checked){

     var target=document.getElementById('parameters');
     var content;

     var target2=document.getElementById('parameters_extra');
     target2.style.visibility = "hidden";

   if (checked){
   if (el == 'ele1_id') {
        content="<table><tr><td><b>select one of the options:</b></td><td>\
<select onChange=add_fields('ele1_id',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value) na
me='ele1_id'>\
<option selected='selected' value='None'>None</option>\
<option value='sele1'>Selection 1</option>\
<option value='sele2'>Selection 2</option>\
</select></td></tr></table>";
    }
   else if (el == 'ele2_id') {

        content="<table><tr><td><b>select one of the options:</b></td><td> \
  <select onChange=add_fields('ele2_id',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value) 
name='ele2_id'> \
<option selected='selected' value='None'>None</option>\
<option value='sele1'>Selection A</option>\
<option value='sele2'>Selection B</option>\
 </select></td></tr></table>";

    }
     target.innerHTML = content; 
     target.style.visibility = "visible"; 
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Call `$("blah").tipbox();` again each time it inserts new elements? ps: are you chinese? because the plugin is in chinese...

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize either jQuery's getScript function to load a script after dynamic loading, or use delegate()/on()/live() within jquery to bind the event to elements loaded dynamically.

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ (depreciated)
http://api.jquery.com/live/ (depreciated)
http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

You see the problem lies in that jquery or even javascript itself cannot attach an event to content that does not exist, and thus, if an element is loaded after jquery has attached an event to an element type, that event is NOT attached to the new element. So to fix this, Jquery gets the parent element of the element (through delegate/live/on) and attaches the event on the fly. This is really cool in that it allows the event to attach on demand instead of bogging down javascript with 1000 event bindings in the case that someone where to attach an event on every row of a table or similiar.

Alternatively, although more messy, less exact, and for sure less efficient if this dynamic content only loads once or so, you could use getScript() to load the script on the fly along with the content. :)

Let me know if this is helpful. :)

Comment: the syntax of the plugin is `$("a.tipMsg").tipbox();`, and how do you use `.on` on it?

Comment: ok... what is the parent element? the div that you are loading into or what have you?

Comment: $("parent").on("mouseover", function(event){ $("a.tipMsg").tipbox(); }); -- might work

Comment: where parent is the parent element

Comment: thanks, Ryan, for your reply but either I do something wrong or the case  
is more complicated.In my case a content of a div element is added by my  
js function as content="whatever dependent on selected option contains    
select element"; target.innerHTML = content; target.style.visibility =    
"visible"; Then user selects one more option in the select element, then  
content of another div element appears. And there an element contains
assigned tipbox

Comment: I assume $("parent").on("mouseover", function(event){ $("a.tipMsg").tipbox(); }); has to be in the main code, am I right?

Comment: The div that is going to contain the links is the "parent." So in your case it would be where "then content of another div element appears." As long as the div is on the page when it loads, you can put it in the $("document").ready(); function or whatever :) hope that helps

Comment: @Ryan - Why don't you answer it as an answer?